# Thunderbird "Tags" in IMAP / PHP

Tags: php, tags, imap, thunderbird

Thunderbird allows to flag messages with predefined (or own) Tags, e.g. "To Do", "Later". (Press "1" while reading a msg to see.)

These tags are replicated to the IMAP server (I verified that by using two TB clients: I saw the same tags on both clients).

How can I access the tag information in PHP using the standard IMAP class (e.g.: msg has set tag "To Do")?

I found an old reference http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2007/02/alternate-imap-solution-for-php-pear-net_imap to net_imap http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IMAP, claiming the "standard" IMAP class cannot do this - but the Net_IMAP package doesn't seem to be updated for quite some time, so I am skeptical to adopt it...

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer how to do that via PHP but good enough where to start:

- [Server-Side Message Labels](http://deflexion.com/2006/05/server-side-message-labels)
- idea how to [handle via IMAP](http://www.grimeton.com/custom-tags-with-thunderbird-stored-on-imap-server/)

Answer (score -1):

`$messages = imap_search($imap_stream, 'To Do');`

[PHP.net: imap_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php)